# Simulating VolumeDown + Power button to capture screen programmatically from my Android service

Tags: android

In Android Ice Cream Sandwich version, the key combo VolumeDown+Power button does screencapture. I was trying to do the same programmatically by sending key events from a background android service. But there are 2 issues,

1. I have to hold the VolumeDown key until power button is pressed, but I am not finding any instrumentation api sendKeysSync() etc.. which sends only Key down event of a button\keycode.
2. Sending KEYCODE_POWER doesn't work at all.

Please let me know if these are constraints in Android ICS(Ice Cream Sandwich) version itself for various reasons or else is it possible?

Also if there is any other way of doing screencapture from background without rooting the phone, let me know..

-Thx in Adv
-rahul

Answer (score 1):

Services are not allowed to inject events (Key, touch etc..) into activities. This was a choice made by the system designers to prevent software from taking "control" of the device away from the user.

If software running in the background were able to do this it would be trivially easy to do incredibly malicious things.

Comment: Well in that case, this can be done from the Activity only right?

Comment: you can inject events into your own Activities using the [Instrumentation APIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html) You cannot inject events into any Activities that are not your own on a stock device using public APIs.